# what to use instead of scrollRangeToVisible in iOS7 or TextKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextview, textkit

In previous versions of iOS, my `UITextView` will scroll to the bottom using

```
[displayText scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,[displayText.text length])];
```

or

```
CGFloat topCorrect = displayText.contentSize.height -[displayText bounds].size.height;
topCorrect = (topCorrect<0.0?0.0:topCorrect);
displayText.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x=0, .y=topCorrect};
```

But the former will now have the weird effect of starting at the top of a long length of text and animating the scroll to the bottom each time I append text to the view. Is there a way to pop down to the bottom of the text when I add text?

Answer (score 3):

```
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1,0)];
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

This really works for me in iOS 7.1.2.

Answer (score 3):

For future travelers, building off of @mikeho's post, I found something that worked wonders for me, but is a bit simpler.

1) Be sure your `UITextView`'s `contentInset`s are properly set & your textView is already `firstResponder()` before doing this.
2) After my the insets are ready to go, and the cursor is active, I call the following function:

```
private func scrollToCursorPosition() {
    let caret = textView.caretRectForPosition(textView.selectedTextRange!.start)
    let keyboardTopBorder = textView.bounds.size.height - keyboardHeight!

   // Remember, the y-scale starts in the upper-left hand corner at "0", then gets
   // larger as you go down the screen from top-to-bottom. Therefore, the caret.origin.y
   // being larger than keyboardTopBorder indicates that the caret sits below the
   // keyboardTopBorder, and the textView needs to scroll to the position.
   if caret.origin.y > keyboardTopBorder {
        textView.scrollRectToVisible(caret, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug in iOS 7. Toggling scrollEnabled on the UITextView seems to fix it:

```
[displayText scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,[displayText.text length])];
displayText.scrollEnabled = NO;
displayText.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: @stian-høiland appears to be correct that this workaround no longer works.

Comment: @user3907849 has a working solution. The important bit is to set `scrollEnabled = NO` before calling `scrollRangeToVisible:`. Using the whole string or just the last character will both work to scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think your parameters are reversed in `NSMakeRange`. *Location* is the first one, then how many you want to select (*length*).

```
NSMakeRange(0,[displayText.text length])
```

...would create a selection starting with the 0th (first?) character and going the entire length of the string. To scroll to the bottom you probably just want to select a single character at the end.

This is working for me in iOS SDK 7.1 with Xcdoe 5.1.1.

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1,0)];
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

I do this as I add text programmatically, and the text views stays at the bottom like Terminal or command line output.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set the bounds for the `UITextView`. It does not trigger scrolling and has an immediate effect of repositioning what is visible. You can do this by finding the location of the caret and then repositioning:

```
- (void)userInsertingNewText {
    UITextView *textView;
    // find out where the caret is located
    CGRect caret = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start];
    // there are insets that offset the text, so make sure we use that to determine the actual text height
    UIEdgeInsets textInsets = textView.textContainerInset;
    CGFloat textViewHeight = textView.frame.size.height - textInsets.top - textInsets.bottom;
    // only set the offset if the caret is out of view
    if (textViewHeight < caret.origin.y) {
        [self repositionScrollView:textView newOffset:CGPointMake(0, caret.origin.y - textViewHeight)];
    }
}

/**
 This method allows for changing of the content offset for a UIScrollView without triggering the scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method.
 */
- (void)repositionScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView newOffset:(CGPoint)offset {
    CGRect scrollBounds = scrollView.bounds;
    scrollBounds.origin = offset;
    scrollView.bounds = scrollBounds;
}
```