# UITextView always scrolls from the beginning when using scrollRangeToVisible()

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm debugging a `UITextView` which logs my operation.

e.g. If I press a special button on the screen, this `UITextView` will show which button I just pressed. It will log more as I pressed more buttons, so I can easily scroll the `UITextView` to see my past operation.

Because the `UITextView` itself doesn't scroll with increasing text, so I try to make it scroll to the last line when something is logged into it.
I try to use the **scrollRangeToVisible()** method below

```
history.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(count(history.text!) - 1, 1))
```

Here history is a `UITextView` outlet.

The problem is, this method always makes the `UITextView` to scroll from the beginning to the designated `NSRange`. More specifically, it will reset the view to the beginning of the text and then scroll down to wherever the `NSRange` is. I want it to `scroll` directly down,

Can someone solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link ([what to use instead of scrollRangeToVisible in iOS7 or TextKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224765/what-to-use-instead-of-scrollrangetovisible-in-ios7-or-textkit)) suggests turning scrolling off, do the change then switch it on.

```
history.scrollEnabled = NO;
[history scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(history.text.length - 1,0)];
history.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

EDIT

Solved after discussion using:

```
history.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;
```

Saw this here: [UITextView setText should not jump to top in ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038082/uitextview-settext-should-not-jump-to-top-in-ios8)

Comment: I'm using iOS 8.3, it seems this solution doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway : )

Comment: Another option is to disable the scroll before you add the new text, then enable it after. Perhaps the insert of text is resetting something scroll related causing it to warp to the top first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453108/smooth-uitextview-auto-scroll-to-bottom-of-frame-solved

Comment: This is the same solution you mentioned above, seems not working for me : (

Comment: Not the same. The first was doing the scroll request while scroll is off. The second was to do your text insertion/append while the scroll is off.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read carefully. With the second solution, my UITextView is still disabled (can't scroll) even after scrollEnabled is set to true. This is just a mystery

Comment: Last shot. Try setting `history.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;` Saw this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038082/uitextview-settext-should-not-jump-to-top-in-ios8

Comment: This works for me! Thanks a lot for your patience and brilliance : )